# How to send message to multiple android devices using FCM in Node js?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried sending message to single device i.e. to single Registration id and it worked fine but when tried to add multiple Registration Ids it gives 'InvalidServerResponse' error.
e.g. Works for regTokens = 'regId1';
But doesn't work for  regTokens = ['regId1','regId2'];

```js
var FCM = require('fcm-node');
// Add API Key
var fcm = new FCM('<server-key>');

exports.sendMessage = function (regTokens, messageToSend, callback) {
  var message = { //this may vary according to the message type (single recipient, multicast, topic, et cetera)
      to: regTokens,

      data: { 
        ar_message: messageToSend
      }
  };

    fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something has gone wrong!",err);
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
        }
        callback(err, 'Success');
      });
}
```

Comment: It works for both Registration Ids if sent individually. But doesn't work for array.

Comment: Please make sure the [code is self-contained](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now, we have no idea what `regTokens` is, and that's likely quite crucial to why it fails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: For **v1**, it seems that `registration_ids` is no longer supported. It is strongly suggested that topics be used instead.

---

When sending to specified multiple registration tokens, you must use [`registration_ids`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) instead of `to`. From the docs (emphasis mine):

> This parameter specifies the recipient of a multicast message, a message sent to more than one registration token.
>
> **The value should be an array of registration tokens** to which to send the multicast message. The array must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens. To send a message to a single device, use the to parameter.
>
> Multicast messages are only allowed using the HTTP JSON format.

```
var message = {
    registration_ids: regTokens,

   data: { 
        ar_message: messageToSend
   }
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

An update for this thread: Use `admin.messaging.Messaging.sendToDevice()` to send messages to multiple android devices.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToDevice

> messaging.sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload, options)
>
> - registrationTokens: Array of String (Tokens of the recipients)
> - payload: Message payload
> - options: (Optional) admin.messaging.MessagingOptions

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = {
            // to : "token", //for single device
            registration_ids: ["token1", "token2"], // for Multiple device
            collapse_key: 'your_collapse_key',
            notification: notify,
            data: payload,
         };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

send_fcm_notifications()
function send_fcm_notifications(){ 

// notification object with title and text

var notification = {
  'title': 'Best Deals',
  'text': 'Mobile Devices at 50% off. Only for today'
};

// fcm device tokens array

var fcm_tokens = ["Key 1", "Key 2"]

var notification_body = {
    'notification': notification,
          'registration_ids': fcm_tokens
  }


fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {

        'method': 'POST',

        'headers': {
          // replace authorization key with your key
          'Authorization': 'key=' + 'Authorization Key',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

         'body': JSON.stringify(notification_body)
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) 
        console.error(error);
      })
}
```

Comment: Please consider an [edit] to your answer to explain the code that you have posted.