# how to send notification to multiple devices using node-fcm

Tags: node.js, express, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Notification is not working while app is closed

const token = ["AAASDfsadfasdfaFDSDFSDLFJLSDAJF;DSJFAsdfdsfsdf"];

```
app.get('/send-notfication', (req, res) => {
        
        var FCM = require('fcm-node');
        var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);
     
        var messageToSend = "Hi there this is message";

        var message = {
         to: token,

         data: {
           ar_message: messageToSend,
         },
        };
        
        fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
            if (err) {
                console.log("Something has gone wrong!", err);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response.results);
                res.send("Successfully sent")
            }
        });
    })
```

Question is how to set notification title in it ? and notification is not working app is closed neither in background nor in foreground why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send message to multiple android devices using FCM in Node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391683/how-to-send-message-to-multiple-android-devices-using-fcm-in-node-js)

Comment: I believe no loop is require here and notification is not working in background

Comment: <pre>Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way ..

Use "registration_ids" instead of "to" if tokens are in array and pass info into data object.

```
app.get("/send-fcm-notification", (req, res) => {
  var FCM = require("fcm-node");
  var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);
  var message = {

   registration_ids: token,

    data: {
      title: "Hi there this is title",
      message: "Hi there this is message"
    },

  };

  fcm.send(message, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Something has gone wrong!", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response.results);
      res.send("Successfully sent");
    }
  });
});
```